# Error al intentar lanzar un segundo emulador

Tags: android

Buenas, al intentar lazar un emulador cuando ya hay otro corriendo me devuelve el siguiente error:
*Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
Hax is enabled
Warning: requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.*
Gracias desde ya por cualquier comentario.

Comment: Hola josetuzin, no es común usar 2 emuladores al mismo tiempo, me da curiosidad saber porque tratas de cargar 2, bueno para solucionar esto, simplemente aumenta la RAM para la VM.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje te muestra cual es el problema:

> Cannot launch AVD in emulator. Output: Hax is enabled Warning:
>   requested ram_size 1024M too big, reduced to 512M Hax ram_size
>   0x20000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

Accede a tus Dispositivos Virtuales (Virtual Devices) desde el icono señalado, selecciona la opción `"Edit this AVD"`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ve a opciones avanzadas, `"Show Advanced Settings"` y en la sección `"Memory and Storage"` (Memoria y almacenamiento) aunmenta el tamaño del Heap de la maquina virtual y para finalizar el botón `"finish"`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto permite aumentar la RAM disponible para la `Maquina virtual de Java` (JVM) para que pueda alojar aplicaciones que se ejecuten en el dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas noches

Deberias aumentar el Heap del ABD

En tu AVD Manager

```
- Clica editar en tu emulador
- "Mostrar configuracion avanzada" abajo de todo.
- Ve a: "Memoria y Almacenamiento"
- Edita el Valor VM heap a 512 MB
- Listo
```

Algunas imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ami me sirvio, fijate si te sirve, saludos